# Why isn't -r working for rsync on Windows?

Tags: windows, cygwin, rsync

I am running this from my command prompt:
`rsync -rltz --executability -C --filter=':- .gitignore' -e "ssh -i /cygdrive/c/Users/dstein/.ssh/id_rsa"   myfolder/ root@site.local:/path/to/place`

I have my `PATH` environment avriable pointing to `cygwin/bin` so I can use `rsync` without being in cygwin, which was causing a number of other issues.

I finally got it working so if I change a file in `myfolder` it uploads to `place`. However if I edit any files that are further nested in `myfolder` the above command is not working for those.

**EDIT**
It turns out that it's not the depth, but this specific folder with the name `core` It has the same permissions as all the other folders that are syncing fine.

Comment: Also tried `-a` to kicks to no avail

Comment: Is your directory named `core` by any chance?

Comment: You missed my edit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your issue is with the `-C` flag. `rsync`'s `-C` flag is the cvs exclude rule. It automatically ignores files that matches CVS's internal rules for excluding files.

These excludes are, from `man rsync(1)`:

```
RCS SCCS CVS CVS.adm RCSLOG cvslog.* tags TAGS .make.state .nse_depinfo *~ #* .#*  ,*  _$*  *$
*.old *.bak *.BAK *.orig *.rej .del-* *.a *.olb *.o *.obj *.so *.exe *.Z *.elc *.ln core 
.svn/ .git/ .hg/ .bzr/
```

The rule your directory fell afoul of was the `core` at the end of line 2.

Answer (score 0):

Let me delete all and insert as we crossed posted. If you remove  the trailing / from myfolder/ the whole directory will be copied. But you will have myfolder inside place. I don't get why -r is not working.

Bung in -vv to get more info.